# print one element from one column separated by comma and file separated by tab

Tags: awk, sed

I have one big file with ~8 million rows. The file is tab delimited, however in second column some fields are comma separated. Here is an example how my file looks:

```
7 rs3752712,rs3752713 1542124 A G 0.211217 0.590887  
7 rs7806171 1542125 A G 0.554353 0.40921  
7 rs185709210 1542177 G A 0.510209 0.0081452
```

In this example I want to remove the second item from second column (`rs3752713`) on row number 1. The desired output should look like this:

```
7 rs3752712 1542124 A G 0.211217 0.590887  
7 rs7806171 1542125 A G 0.554353 0.40921  
7 rs185709210 1542177 G A 0.510209 0.0081452
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to remove everything from 2nd field starting from comma in it then following may help you here.

```
awk '{sub(/\,.*/,"",$2)} 1'  Input_file
```

Add `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` in case your Input_file is TAB delimited and you want output as TAB delimited too.